# How can I change the order of iOS Kif tests?

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, kif-framework

As far as I can tell the tests in my `KIFTestScenario+EXAdditions` just go in alphabetical order.  How can I get the tests to go in an order that I want.  I would rather not simply name them like this `scenarioToATestLogin`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We used to have that problem, but now we subclass the KifTestController, and in that controller we add our KifTestScenario's like this:

```
- (void)initializeScenarios {
    [self addScenario:[KIFTestScenario scenarioTestMediaPlayer]];
    [self addScenario:[KIFTestScenario scenarioTestVideoPlayer]];
    [self addScenario:[KIFTestScenario scenarioTestSharing]];
    [self addScenario:[KIFTestScenario scenarioTestContentView]];
}
```

Then in our AppDelegate, we start up the KiffTest's in this method:

```
- (void)runIntegrationTests {
    [[OurTestController sharedInstance] startTestingWithCompletionBlock:^{
        exit([[OurTestController sharedInstance] failureCount]);
    }];
}
```

And our scenarios run in the order that we have added them above.

Comment: Would you please illustrate this in Swift 3.0 and KIF latest version (eg. 3.2.1)? Thank you.